# Show map values in ng-select

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to put map values(1,2,3) into select.

```
<select ng-model="group" ng-options="g.key for g in groups"></select>
```

`$scope.groups` is map `{'a':'1', 'b':'2', 'c':'3'}` 
I know that by this code :

```
<select ng-model="group" ng-options="key for (key, g) in groups"></select>
```

I can put keys. I've tried `ng-options="value for(value,g) in groups"` but it failed.

Comment: Have you tried `ng-options="g for (key, g) in groups"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside this syntax:

```
ng-options="key for (key, value) in groups"
```

The `(key, value)` bit describes the key/value pair.  So, `value` in your case is the value.

So, to use the value you would simply do this:

```
ng-options="value for (key, value) in groups"
```